# React-native on android 4.0.3. Possible?

Tags: android, react-native, gradlew

I am trying to create a react-native app to run on emu with 4.0.3 android. When i try to start the app. I got this error:

```
app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE   
app:installDebug FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> Failed to install on any devices.
```

If i run on 6.0 android, it works normally; but not with 4.0.3 version. is there anything i need to config ??!!

Please help.

Comment: Do you have a `targetSdkVersion 23` in your build.gradle?

Comment: Yes, i have one. Actually i found the solution already. 

I need to add "<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook.react"/>" in a  project's Manifest. to be able to change the minSdkVersion.

Comment: When you find answers like this, could you submit the answer to your own question.  I am a n00b, so I have your magical line ;) and a vague idea of where to put it.  That will most likely be what I need, but a longer answer with more detailed instructions would erase any doubt.

Answer (score 4):

React native only supports API 16+ (Android 4.1) since it uses [Choreographer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Choreographer.html)